# spdlog: failing to flush/write to file

Tags: c++, spdlog

I feel like a fool asking this, as it is about as trivial example as I can think of, but it's holding me up.

I've implemented a very basic console-and-file logger:

```
    auto logger = spdlog::basic_logger_mt("console and file logger", filepath);
#ifdef NDEBUG
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::info); // Set global log level to info
#else
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::trace); // Set global log level to everything
#endif
    spdlog::set_pattern("%^%l: %v%$");    // see https://github.com/gabime/spdlog/wiki/3.-Custom-formatting
    spdlog::flush_on(spdlog::level::info);
```

This writes to the console perfectly in colours, but although it creates the log file, it never writes to it.

I want to try flushing it manually, but there is no spdlog::flush.

I had originally implemented this with two sinks (one console, one file), and had a *similar* problem: except in that case it would write the *first* (and only first) message to the log file, so long as it was an error.

I'm sorry for asking such a noddy question...

------------------------------ EDIT ---------------------------------------

Attempt 1 (from multi-sink example):

```
    // Creating console logger --------------------
    auto console_sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::stdout_color_sink_mt>();

    // Creating file logger -----------------------
    auto file_sink = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::basic_file_sink_mt>(filepath);

    // Creating multi-logger ----------------------
    spdlog::logger logger("console and file", { console_sink, file_sink });
    spdlog::flush_on(spdlog::level::info);
```

Result: log file is created, console logging is great, but file remains determinedly empty.

Attempt 2 (from basic example):

```
    // Creating the logger ------------------------
    auto logger = spdlog::basic_logger_mt("console and $ME file", filepath);
    spdlog::set_level(spdlog::level::trace); // Set global log level to everything
    spdlog::flush_on(spdlog::level::info);
```

Result: the same

The only time I seem to have got further is when I set the log level to "error", and then if the very next log is an error, it appears in the file.  No other message appears in the file.

I have also been unable to find the manual flush.  I've tried using the example:

```
spdlog::apply_all([&](std::shared_ptr<spdlog::logger> l) {l->flush(); });
```

but this doesn't appear to do anything...

Comment: Please provide a a complete reproducable example

Comment: try using the loggers methods instead of spdlog’s. or alternitavly, register the logger using spdlog:register_logger(logger).

Comment: @GabiMe - I then get an error from throw spdlog_ex("logger with name '" + logger_name + "' already exists");

Comment: You need to call it only once per logger's name

Comment: It appears that the spdlog::basic_logger_mt has automatically registered the logger (which is good), so that you don't need to do the register_logger step.  This fits with the rest of the behaviour (because it logs to console as expected).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, after going through the spdlog code line-by-line, I've found the source of unexpected behaviour.

I've been using the

```
spdlog::error(message);
```

and related functions to do the logging, as these don't require creating any singletons or anything.

Looking at the code, these functions **always** use the default logger, and the method spdlog:register_logger does not set the default logger (I don't know what it does).

If you use the following code instead:

```
spdlog::set_default_logger(logger);
```

It seems to work OK.

Comment: Thanks Mike ;) the spdlog API could do with some simplification.

Comment: conceptually, after creating a logger with `auto logger = spdlog::basic_logger_mt("console and file logger", filepath);`, you should have known to use it (e.g., `logger->error(message)`) in your code. How could the namespace-scoped method possibly know which logger you meant to use?